# How can I loop add css properties with JS/Jquery with :after pseudo class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

With the help of JS/Jquery I am trying to add css after a last child element but am completely lost on how to do that! More specifically I would like to implement the following three times, so I get three "dots".

```css
.milestone:last-child {
  position: relative;
  .milestone_line:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    bottom: -25px;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```js
function milestoneEllipsis() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var lastMilestone = $('.milestone:last-child > milestone_line').after("the css content");
    console.log(lastMilestone);
  }
}
```

Comment: jQuery cannot access pseudo elements such as `:after` and `:before`, so the manner you're trying to do this in is not possible. A workaround would be to add a class to the elements using jQuery and then hook the `:after` selector in your CSS from that class

Comment: you can try .after() but it's not a good way
I mean it's better to do it on css

Comment: @LucasLaurens The OP is already using `after()`, but it won't work because it's about injecting content in to the DOm instead of amending CSS